# Shorten the URL dynamically for different API calls

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

In MobileConnect, is there a way to dynamically shorten bitly URLs? For eg., if the SMS API call has 'url' as https://long.url.net/wiki/spaces/longer/data/665092146?u=u1 for user 1 and https://long.url.net/wiki/spaces/longer/data/665092145?u=u2 for user 2, and if the sms content is 'To view details, visit %%url%%', can this url be shortened using Bitly? I don't see any ampscript function that does this. If not possible through ampscript, can we make API call to Bitly services to generate the shortened URL and use it ? Anybody tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an [httpget AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/mobileVariables.htm) call to Bit.ly Api, but they have [API calls/min limit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWU4L/Mobile/imc_Mobile/config_bitly_link_shortening_SMS.html)

> Enterprise: Shorten up to 50,000 links per minute.
>
> Monthly maximum is determined by the terms of the Enterprise account.
>
> Free: Shorten up to 1,000 links per minute.
>
> Monthly maximum is 1,000 links per calendar month.

```
%%[
SET @URL = TRIM(HTTPGet(Concat("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=BITLY_TOKEN&format=txt&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com/mobile/conf.php?mobile=",MOBILE_NUMBER)))
]%%
```